# AzureServicePlan - Monitor storage diskspace

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

We are running three web apps within Azure: tracktable-prod-angular, tracktable-prod-ui, and tracktable-prod-maintenance.

Upon reviewing the monitoring, we currently track whether they are running, CPU time, response time, and errors.

I noticed an option for monitoring the cost of storage, but I would like to explore how we can monitor disk space.

Can someone help me with this question how i can monitor disk space? If monitoring disk space directly is not possible, is there a PowerShell script available for monitoring storage disk usage?

Thank you.

- already searched on the microsoft site and google
- asked the same question on the microsoft forum

my expectation

that i can monitor the diskspace in azure.

Answer (score 0):

The **Disk space** of **Azure Web App depends upon** your **Azure App Service SKU's**. ***Azure Free Plan F1 and Shared Plan D1 has 1 GB of storage. Azure Basic Plan has 10 GB of storage. Azure Standard Plan has 50 GB of storage and Azure Premium Plan has 250 GB of storage***. This is your Azure Web App Disk storage too.

[image]

1. You can monitor the File storage usage of your Web App by visiting your **`Azure Web App > Quotas`** :-

[image]

2. One more option to get detail value is to Call this [**Azure Rest API**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-usages?view=rest-appservice-2022-03-01#code-try-0):-

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62847477/get-azure-app-service-local-disk-usage-programmatically):-

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{name}/usages?api-version=2022-03-01
```

[image]

[image]

3. You can also visit **`Advanced Tools > Go > Kudu > Environment`** and check the File Storage Usage:-

[image]

4. You can also visit the Metrics pane and select File usage to get the Details of Azure Web App space:-

[image]